# Audio Inconsistency - Extremely Puzzling

Tags: jquery, css, html, audio

So, I have a site that is sort of emulating a flash site with jquery and html 5.

Audio is set to play when you hover over the menu items or open the different menus - it works fine in IE 9 (audio isn't supported in 8 or lower) and chrome but NOT FF.

Now here is the puzzling part: it also works fine in FF on my desktop or my testing server, just NOT on the server it needs to work on.

Anybody have any clue what might be going on here?

Site is [here](http://www.0755lounge.com) for reference. Look at it in IE9 or Chrome, then in FF to see what I mean. You can go [here](http://www.blueclick.ca/projects/0755/html/switch) for my testing server in which it works everywhere. Files are identical.

**EDIT**

As per request, here is the way I've got stuff set up (complete code is available by following the previous links and clicking view source)

```
<audio id="open2" preload="auto"><source src="support/media/open2.mp3"></source><source src="support/media/open2.ogg"></source></audio>
```

Later... I add the following code to an element with the last class an integer corresponding to the id of the audio element.. don't get hung up on that stuff though as it clearly does work in other browsers. I also do some browser detection as trying to play the audio will DESTROY the page in IE 8 and under.

```
document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();
```

Comment: I was just working with audio tags for a soundboard HTML5 project and I also saw that it didn't work in FF. I'll take a look in the morning, could you post some demo code?

Comment: @Charlie that should be enough to give a general idea of what's going on - let me know if you want more. The most puzzling thing about this is that if I download the files from the test server (where it works in FF) to my desktop, the sound continues to work in FF, if I then take those files and throw them directly onto the final site through FTP, they cease to sound in FF (but continue to work in IE9 or chrome). So we have the files working in FF both online and offline, but just not on this one server. This makes me feel that its a server config thing but then.. it works in other browsers-_-

Comment: Okay it's working in Safari, next I'll test Firefox... Also, have you tried using the `<audio>` files with the `src=` inside of the tag, instead of it's own separate one, `<audio src="" preload="auto" />` See if you can see anything here too, http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mozilla+audio+tag&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: He needs the multiple sources because Firefox can't play MP3 files with the audio tag; though it sounds like it's trying to anyways. I'd be curious to see what would happen if you exchange the audio load order to load the ogg file first. I'm not sure exactly how FireFox handles loading in this case, but something tells me that it's not handling things in the way that you think it will. If the JS interpreters aren't spitting out errors, I'd bet the problem lies with the fact that FF is trying to load and play an MP3 file.

Comment: @ceprovence Hmm, keen observation and a good suggestion. It wouldn't really explain why it still works on the other server, but this could have caused issues under the right circumstances, didn't turn out to be make a difference though :(

Answer (score 0):

sdo, your files are not the same. I took the source from your site (lounge) and from your test site (blueclick.ca) and compared them. While there are quite a few HTML differences, I feel the following JS logic is your problem. As you can see that the code is different. May be the correct code not being their on your site is causing the problem. It could also be that your server is serving a cached version of the page. Check these and it might help.

Code from your working site:

```
$("#navigation li").click(function() {

        if (!currOpen){
            if (!(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version < 9))
                document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();    
                customToggle($(this));
                currOpen = getId($(this));
        } else if (getId($(this)) == currOpen) {
                $("#"+currOpen).slideToggle('slow');
                currOpen = 0;
        } else {
                $("#"+currOpen).slideToggle('slow');
            if (!(BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version < 9))
                document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();    
                customToggle($(this));
                currOpen = getId($(this));
        }

        function customToggle(obj){
            $("#"+getId(obj)).slideToggle('slow');
        }

        function getId(obj){ return obj.attr('id').substr(4) }

    });
```

Code from your not working site:

```
$("#navigation li").click(function() {

        if (!currOpen){
                if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version < 9){
                 // do something else 
            } else {
                document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();
            }               document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();    
                customToggle($(this));
                currOpen = getId($(this));
        } else if (getId($(this)) == currOpen) {
                $("#"+currOpen).slideToggle('slow');
                currOpen = 0;
        } else {
                $("#"+currOpen).slideToggle('slow');
            if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer" && BrowserDetect.version < 9){
                 // do something else 
            } else {
                document.getElementById('open'+$(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length-1)).play();
            }
                customToggle($(this));
                currOpen = getId($(this));
        }

        function customToggle(obj){
            $("#"+getId(obj)).slideToggle('slow');
        }

        function getId(obj){ return obj.attr('id').substr(4) }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. yea over the past few hours I've made some minor changes to try and clarify the code, removing double negatives etc.. still no success. As I said in my post to Charlie, I can literally FTP the code from my working test server to the lounge server and it will stop working. I thought it might be the cache but this bug is consistent across separate computers/browsers.